# 1 to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

i am trying to create an objectmodel based on a databasemodel. The database model contains foreign key constraints. For example I have 3 tables : Company, Employee and ShareHolder.
A Company has 1 or more Employees, and a Company has 1 or more ShareHolders. The Employee and ShareHolder table have a foreign key reference to the Company table. So when I create my object Model I get:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyID {get;set;}
    List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
    List<ShareHolder> ShareHolders {get;set;}
}
```

Is this the handiest way to do this?

Comment: What is the object model for?  Are you using code fisrt EF or something?  Are you creating a view model?

Comment: yes trying to create a ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks right to me, i would do it the same.

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyID {get;set;}
    List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
    List<ShareHolder> ShareHolders {get;set;}
}

public class Employee
{
    public string CompanyID {get;set;}
    //...
}

public class ShareHolder
{
    public string CompanyID {get;set;}
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the most obvious approach. Especially if your application is Company focused.

Depending on how you will use your objects in your application you might have back links from `Employee` and `ShareHolder`, this way you can easily navigate from `Employee` and `ShareHolder` back to `Company` without excessive searching.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public Company Workplace {get;set;} // might be List<Company> depending on your application needs
}

public class ShareHolder : Person
{
    public List<Company> OwnedCompanies {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its for a view model I'd name it CompanyDisplay or CompanyInput based on what the view is doing.